# Unable to run cucumber 'npm test' command is not working

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I can't execute npm test when running feature file however, i can execute the script via: ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js

When I run the npm i get the following error message: ".' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

The following is cucumber dependencies:

`"@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.3.1", "@cucumber/pretty-formatter": "^1.0.0-alpha.1", "@types/chai": "^4.2.21", "@types/cucumber": "7.0.0", "chai": "^4.3.4", "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.4.0", "cucumber-pretty": "^6.0.0", "ts-node": "^10.1.0", "typescript": "^4.3.5"`

Comment: Have you tried 'npm run test' command.. Also make sure you added a script in package. json as 'test: "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js. Also make sure to run this command from your project root directory..

Answer (score 0):

Run it as npx instead of npm, should wort you out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).